# Alchemy 1.0.1.1 installer throwing an error 1001

Tags: 2013-sp1, a4t

Recently when trying to install Alchemy4Tridion 1.0.1.1 with the msi installer, I got the following error 1001 and not able to install Alchemy4Tridion:

[image]

I am not able to install another Alchemy installer, repair or uninstall the current installer. Alchemy4Tridion just remains in the Programs and Features.

My tridion version is 2013 SP1.

Can anyone, who experienced the similar issue please explain to me:

Why am I getting this error?
How can I resolve this error to use Alchemy in Tridion?

Comment: Are you running the installer as administrator?

Comment: I can't run the installer as administrator (the option in the menu), but I'm logged with a administrator user in the machine.

Comment: Has anyone experienced the similar issue?